# Is anything wrong with putting verb inside this sentence?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

> **Sentence:** "I love creativity and problem solving here"

My questions are:

Is this sentence right or wrong grammatically?

Putting "problem solving" verb inside statement is not allowed in English?

or It should be like : `"I love creativity and solving problems here"`?

Comment: Probably "I love **the** creativity and problem solving here".

Comment: @snailplane so, Is it important to put 'the'? can you explain in answer?

Comment: @krupalshah: because "creativity" doesn't have a location, it's too general. "The creativity here" does, it's more specific. As a typical native speaker, I'm struggling to figure out why, but "I love creativity here" means that "here" is the place I am located whilst loving "creativity" in general. "I love the creativity here" means that "here" is the location of the creativity I love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is okay.

I love *noun* and *noun* is the structure here.

The two words 'problem solving' serves as a noun here. Nevertheless, a little hyphen would make it better and unambiguous.

> [problem-solving (noun)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/problem-solving) - *The process of finding solutions to difficult or complex issues*

So,

> I love creativity and problem-solving here.

Comment: So, it is missing dash(-) only..yes?

Comment: *hyphens* are tricky but I recommend putting it to keep the confusion away. With hyphen, anybody would understand that that is **not** verb but a noun. That's what confused you I guess!